# How to loop through json arrays nested inside json objects

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have this json text which has some symptoms associated with head diseases:

```
    {
    "Head": {
     "Agitation": {
      "conditions": "Generalized anxiety disorder,Medication reaction or side-effect"
                  },
     "Anxiety": {
      "conditions": "Generalized anxiety disorder,Depression (Adult)"
                  },
     "Apathy": {
      "conditions": "Depression (Adult),Medication reaction or side-effect,Dementia in head injury"
               }
            }
    }
```

What I want is to access and display every symptom in this Head block using a for loop, and then access each symptom's conditions and store them separately as arrays.

This java code works but it's functionality is limited:

```
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;
        JSONObject bodyPart = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("Head");
        JSONObject symptoms = (JSONObject) name.get("Agitation");
        String res = (String) symptoms.get("conditions");
        String[] tokens = res.split(","); 
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
            System.out.println(tokens[i]);}
```

Instead of displaying just the conditions of Agitation, how can I display every condition associated with every symptom without having to pass their String values manually into the get methods?

I don't know if I should use JSONArray for "Head" instead of JSONObject to access the symptoms.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys()

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the `org.json` package, you can use `JSONObject`'s `keys()` method to get an iterator over the object's keys.

```
Iterator bodyParts = jsonObject.keys();
while (bodyParts.hasNext()){
    String bodyPart = (String) bodyParts.next();
    JSONObject symptomsJson = jsonObject.getJSONObject(bodyPart);
    Iterator symptoms = symptomsJson.keys();
    // And so on...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My friend, if you're using java, use objects, no plain text, my recommendation is to use [Json.simple](https://howtodoinjava.com/json-simple/json-simple-read-write-json-examples/),

That way you can have `List` of objects and use the properties you want, take a look on the link examples.